# bash: Difference between join and comm

Tags: bash, join, comm

```
# comm -12 /tmp/src /tmp/txt | wc -l
  10338
# join /tmp/src /tmp/txt | wc -l
  10355
```

Both the files are single columns of alphanumeric strings and `sort`-ed. Shouldn't they be the same?

---

Updated following @Kevin-s answer below:

```
cat /tmp/txt | sed 's/^[:space:]*//' > /tmp/stxt
cat /tmp/src | sed 's/^[:space:]*//' > /tmp/ssrc
```

and the result:

```
#join /tmp/ssrc /tmp/stxt | wc -l
516
# comm -12 /tmp/ssrc /tmp/stxt | wc -l
513
```

On manual inspection of the `diff`-s ... the results differ due to some whitespaces that were not taken out by the `sed`.

Comment: This really isn't a bash question.

Comment: @keith Thompson It might be command specific - but I encountered them while choosing them for bash script. Hence the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I haven't used either extensively, but from a quick look at the man pages and test input, it seems that if the two files differ, comm prints both and join only prints matching lines.</strike>  The -12 took care of that.  You could store the output of the two into files and do a diff to see how they differ.

```
$ echo -e '1\n2\n3\n5' > a
$ echo -e '1\n2\n4\n5' > b
$ comm a b
                1
                2
3
        4
                5
$ join a b
1
2
5
$
```

Edit: 
Join only compares the first whitespace-separated field but comm compares the whole line.  Any whitespace on the line will therefore make the output differ.

Comment: I'm using `comm -12` that suppress lines unique to FILE1, FILE2. the `diff`-s are too big - hurts eyes ;)

Comment: I see now I missed that.  After further review of the man pages, it appears that join joins on the first whitespace-delimited field, but comm joins on the full line.  Are there spaces in the input files?

Comment: Good point ... I'll try to `sed` up the spaces and see if there is a difference ... :D

Comment: the problems were indeed due to rouge whitespace. Updated the question with the changes made to the file. The minor difference between the results that I have now, on manual inspection reveals are all because of whitespaces - wondering why `[:space:]` didn't take them down. Anyregex, can you please update your answer so that I can accept it? And mega thanks :D

Comment: I understood that rouge is French for red, but I don't know what the -s to diff does.

Comment: s/rouge/rogue ... :P

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of differences between `comm` and `join`:

1. `comm` compares whole lines; `join` compares fields within lines.
2. `comm` prints whole lines; `join` can print selected parts of lines.

When you have a single column of data in each file, there is relatively little difference.  When you have multiple columns, there can be a lot of difference.

Also note that under the right circumstances, `join` can output multiple copies of the data from one file while joining with different lines from the other file.  This looks to me like your problem; you probably have some duplicate values in one of the files.  Suppose you have:

```
src           txt
123           123
              123
              123
```

If you do `comm -12 src txt`, you will get one line of output; if you do `join src txt`, you will get three lines of output.  This is expected.

The `join` command can also handle 'outer joins' where data is missing from the second file for a line in the first file (a LEFT OUTER JOIN in terms of SQL) or vice versa (a RIGHT OUTER JOIN), or both at once (a FULL OUTER JOIN).

All-in-all, `join` is a more complex command, but it is attempting to do a more complex job.  Both are useful; but they are useful in different places.

Comment: thanks for the answer, really informative. I generally `sort -k` on the column, but have never been comfortable using `join` - and find myself writing long strips of `awk` associative arrays to compare files .. lulz :D

Answer (score 2):

The main utility of `join` is to select lines which share one field, like you can do in a database.  Say you have the following files:

```
File A
Alice  24
Bill   16
Claire 31
John   10
John  -14

File B
Bill   Copenhagen
John   Adelaide
```

... you can select the "John" and "Bill" lines from File A by giving File B as the file to join with, and the first field of both as the field to join on.  The requirement that both files have to be sorted **on that field** is rather cumbersome in practice, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[[:space:]]` (instead of `[:space:]`) to strip whitespace with `sed`.

```
# compare
{
echo '   abc' | sed 's/^[:space:]*//'
echo '   abc' | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//'
}
```